# SQL Server - select distinct rows by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following format

```
Name   someString     theValue 
abc    bla bla         3
abc    bla bla         3
abd    bla bla         5
abd    bla bla         5
xfz    ffs ds ds       50
xfz    ffs ds ds       50
```

expected result:

```
Name   someString     theValue 
abc    bla bla         3
abd    bla bla         5
xfz    ffs ds ds       50
```

Tried to solve my problem using this query:

```
Select Name, someString, theValue count(*) FROM myTable
        GROUP BY Name, someString, theValue
          HAVING count(*) = 1
```

The logic here being: append to each row a count number, and select only the first one which was counted per set of rows.

This shrinks my result from 2160 rows to 40, but there are still duplicates here.

**My question is**: Is the logic I used in the query corect (for filtering out duplicate rows by 2 columns), and would you have written this in another way?

Using SQL Server 2012

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you just use `SELECT DISTINCT`?  And where does `theValue` come into play?

Comment: Your logic is not correct because you only want one per group but your `HAVING count(*)=1` selects only groups where only one row exists. You want the first per group but there is no order-column. What determines the first?

Comment: tried. If i use `select discting * from myTable` i will have the same number `2160` rows returned. @Siyual

Comment: If you expect `theValue` in the result, why are you not using it in your query?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT DISTINCT *`... use `SELECT DISTINCT Name, someString, theValue` .....

Comment: If you really have to use HAVING, does changing it to `HAVING count(*)>1` work?

Comment: @MartaG , sorry, didn't see the mistake. Wrote this as an example based on my query. That one I can't post. But i am using it in my query. I edited my post. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @MartaG if i change it to `count(*) > 1` i get 300 rows returned. With 1 i get 40 and I didn't count manually but should be like 15

Comment: The code sample and the sample query both reference three columns that are indistinguishable in how you're using them - but you've written, both in the title and in the question that you want this to be for "2 columns" - so, which two columns are we wanting to make distinct here?

Comment: @Siyual tried `SELECT DISTINCT Name, someString, theValue` didn't help

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `name` and `someString` . I want to filter the duplicate rows based on those 2

Comment: Okay, so presuming there are multiple values for `theValue` for some of these rows - *what* value should we be selecting for it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is not the case. There is only one value if the first two columns are the same.

Comment: What is your REAL expected result?  You are selecting a count in your query, but do not have a count in your posted "expected result".  What is an example of what you are getting in your current results that you do not want in your expected results?   As posted, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a simple aggregation as the simplest approach:

```
select name, someString, min(theValue) as theValue
from t
group by name, someString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely what you want to do is

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, someString, theValue FROM myTable
```

Or if you need to know how many occurances then

```
SELECT Name, someString, theValue, Count(*) as ct FROM myTable GROUP BY Name, someString, theValue
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your expected output this query can be simply done as

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, someString, theValue
FROM myTable
```

resultset will have distinct combination of Name, someString, theValue.

If you also want count of each combination then you can implement it as

```
SELECT Name, someString, theValue, count(*) combination_count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name, someString, theValue
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a long shot, but all you have written about the issue suggests that these duplicates are not actually duplicates. Perhaps there are some trailing spaces which cause troubles? In that case, the following should work:
`SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(name), RTRIM(someString), theValue FROM myTable;`

If the problem with duplicates is with theValue, you can try using:

`SELECT DISTINCT name, someString, first_value(theValue) over (partition by name, someString) FROM myTable;`

Comment: Unless they've got weird settings in effect, values with trailing spaces would be grouped/distinct-ed together with values without.

Comment: If the spaces are an issue your would want to use RTRIM(LTRIM(<field>)) to remove all trailing and prepended spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove "theValue" from both the select and group by statements.

You properly have multiple "theValue" for individual names / someStrings.

Comment: but i need to select the column `theValue`. That's the whole point of this.